# Eloquent: Group / Distinct / Count users drop-off from table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've a couple of tables, naming:

```
Actions
- id
- session_id
- package_code
- action_type
- action_name

Packages
- id
- package_code
- is_used
```

What I'd like is basically to get the distinct session_id and grab the last action_type=pageview as well as count how many times this happened for each.

So I'm trying to obtain the last pageview seen by a determined user and count how many times this happened for the given pageview.

So far I've been trying with things like...

```
    Action::
    where('package_code', '!=', null)
    ->whereActionType('pageview')
    ->whereHas('package', function($query){
        return $query->where('is_used', true);
    })
    ->orderBy('action_type')->last()
    ->distinct('sessid')
    ->count('action_type)
    ->get();
```

But I'm a bit lost on how to concanate everything.
Essentially I'd like to get the results as in

```
pageview: 'somename'
count: 123
pageview: 'other'
count: 122
```

Thank you

Comment: I think you want to look at groupBy instead of distinct. Also ->last() should be ->latest() if you want to sort by date descendingly.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start by getting a working query in raw sql